# How to get running (cumulative) string aggregation of distinct value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Not sure if this question has been asked before, tried searching for it but could not find anything relevant.

I am trying to get a string aggregate that is cumulative i.e. running aggregation of only the distinct values. Here is an example of the result I am looking for.

I tried using the `string_agg` function but that only aggregates at a user-month level, not getting a running aggregate.

Ideally it has to be sorted in order but if that's not possible, just the unique combo is fine.

```
User    month   event   running agg
User1   Jan A   A
User1   Feb A   A
User1   Mar B   A+B
User1   Apr B   A+B
User1   May C   A+B+C
User1   Jun D   A+B+C+D
User1   Jul A   A+B+C+D
User1   Aug B   A+B+C+D
User1   Sep A   A+B+C+D
```

Comment: From site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) ps: I cannot see your image

Comment: The order of `event` matters ? I mean `A+B` and `B+A` can be considered same ?

Comment: @Jaytiger Yes, order would be preferable. But if that's not possible, then its ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is simple solution for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag), 
  STRING_AGG(IF(flag,event, NULL), '+') OVER(PARTITION BY user ORDER BY month) AS  running_agg
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY user, event ORDER BY month) = 1 AS flag
  FROM your_table
)
```

If applied to sample data as in your example

```
WITH your_table AS (
  SELECT 'User1' user, 1 month, 'A' event UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User1', 2, 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User1', 3, 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User1', 4, 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User1', 5, 'C' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User1', 6, 'D' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User1', 7, 'A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User1', 8, 'B' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'User1', 9, 'A' 
) 
SELECT * EXCEPT(flag), 
  STRING_AGG(IF(flag,event, NULL), '+') OVER(PARTITION BY user ORDER BY month) AS  running_agg
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY user, event ORDER BY month) = 1 AS flag
  FROM your_table
)
ORDER BY user, month
```

the output is

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There might be other efficient ways, but below recursive approach would be one option for your question.

```sql
-- sample table
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample_table AS
SELECT 'User1' user, month, event
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 9)) month WITH offset
  JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT('AABBCDABA', '')) event WITH offset USING (offset);

-- recursive query starts here
WITH RECURSIVE sample_table0 AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY month) rn 
    FROM sample_table
),
aggs AS (
  SELECT *, [event] running_agg FROM sample_table0 WHERE rn = 1
   UNION ALL
  SELECT t.*,
         IF(t.event IN UNNEST(a.running_agg), a.running_agg, a.running_agg || [t.event])
    FROM aggs a JOIN sample_table0 t ON a.rn + 1 = t.rn
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(rn) REPLACE(ARRAY_TO_STRING(running_agg, '+') AS running_agg)
  FROM aggs
 ORDER BY user, month;

-- query result
+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
| user  | month | event | running_agg |
+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
| User1 |     1 | A     | A           |
| User1 |     2 | A     | A           |
| User1 |     3 | B     | A+B         |
| User1 |     4 | B     | A+B         |
| User1 |     5 | C     | A+B+C       |
| User1 |     6 | D     | A+B+C+D     |
| User1 |     7 | A     | A+B+C+D     |
| User1 |     8 | B     | A+B+C+D     |
| User1 |     9 | A     | A+B+C+D     |
+-------+-------+-------+-------------+
```